# Can I use the Bluetooth serial port in Windows Phone 7.1 and up?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, bluetooth

I want to develop an app for the Windows Phone app store that communicates with my car's OBD2 port via Bluetooth.

Long story short, the app will use the bluetooth serial port to send a hex value and retrieve the corresponding value in the ECU's register. There's an android app called Torque which does this.

I can't figure out how to use the serial port though. The only bluetooth functionality mentioned is high-level stuff like pushing objects, pairing, etc. But nothing about setting baud rates or writing to a specific COM port.

Is this possible on WP7/*? Or alternatively, how can I *make* this possible and get my app approved for distribution?

UPDATE: I haven't been able to get my hands on a WP8 device yet, so I can't verify whether or not this is possible using SSP.

As a bonus note in case you came here looking for alternatives: you can also NOT connect to ad-hoc wifi connections, so the wife-based OBD2 adapters are no good either. There is an ugly way of connecting to the latter which involves having a laptop in your car which is simultaneously connected in ad-hoc mode the the device and is also acting as a wifi hotspot. It is utterly impractical.

Comment: I don't have code to show around what I've tried because I frankly don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Bluetooth Serial Port (SSP) is not possible with public APIs of Windows Phone 7.x. As you've kind of guessed already, the app will likely not be approved for the marketplace if private APIs are P/invoked or otherwise used.

Consider upgrading to Windows Phone 8 as the Bluetooth SSP is partially available there, see [Nokias Developer site](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Introduction_to_Bluetooth_support_on_Windows_Phone_8#Serial_Port_Profile_.28SSP.29) for example.

Comment: Upgrading to WP8 is not a bad idea.

Comment: Also, I can't begin to tell you how useful that link was. Thanks. There's actually a sample app that seems to be exactly what I need to get started.

Comment: Just a note: you can't upgrade from WP7 to 8 on the same device.